# Кодировка задачи Redmine при выполнении скрипта powershell (REST API)

Tags: rest, redmine

Пишу синхронизацию Service Desk Plus + Redmine. Проблема с кодировкой (из SDP получаю файл JSON, кодирую в utf-8, забираю переменные, передаю xml в redmine с нужными параметрами. Задача в Redmine создается, проблема с кодировкой:"????????" вместо кириллицы. 
Текст скрипта:

```
 param (
[string]$json = "none"
)
$jsondata = get-content $json -encoding UTF8
$obj = ConvertFrom-Json $jsondata
$ticket = $obj.request.WORKORDERID
$apikey = ""
$baseurl = "http://localhost"
$header = @{"Content-Type"="application/xml"}
$url = $baseurl + "/issues.xml?key=" + $apikey
$xml = @"
<issue>
  <project_id>55</project_id>
  <subject>test</subject>
  <description>тест</description>
  <custom_fields type="array">
        <custom_field id="2">
             <value>test</value>
         </custom_field>
  </custom_fields>
</issue>
"@

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $xml -headers $header
```

P.S. в редмайн кодовая таблица базы "UTF8".